# PYQT5 Physics Calculator

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I am making a physics calculator that takes values from the person and uses a calculation to show the answer. the problem is that when i press submit to take the values and save them as variable and show a button to show the answer, the app closes and sublime text shows REPL closed. i have no idea why. please help

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QPushButton
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QToolTip , QCheckBox, QLCDNumber,QLineEdit,QInputDialog#just compile the modules like this
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QLabel
def ObjectDensity():
    dflabel = QLabel("Please Enter Density of Fluid: ",w)
    dflabel.move(25,220)
    dflabel.show()
    dfte = QLineEdit(w)
    dfte.move(25,260)
    dfte.show()
    Weight2 = QLabel("Please Enter Weight:",w)
    Weight2.move(25,300)
    Weight2.show()
    Wte = QLineEdit(w)
    Wte.move(25,340)
    Wte.show()
    AIW2 = QLabel("Enter Apperent Immersed Weight: ",w)
    AIW2.move(25,380)
    AIW2.show()
    aiwte = QLineEdit(w)
    aiwte.move(25,420)
    aiwte.show()
    ansbutton = QPushButton("Submit",w)
    ansbutton.move(50,480)
    ansbutton.show()
    ansbutton.clicked.connect(lambda: f1(dfte,Wte,aiwte,ansdo))
    # df1 = dfte.text()
    # w2 = Wte.text()
    # aiw6 = aiwte.text()
def f1(dfte,Wte,aiwte,ansdo):

    df1 = int(dfte.text())
    w2 = int(Wte.text())
    aiw6 = int(aiwte.text())
    # ansdo = ((w2/w2-aiw6)*df1)
    # ans4 = int(ansdo)
    ans = QPushButton("press to show answer",w)
    ans.move(50,250)
    ans.show()
    ans.clicked.connect(lambda:f2(w2,aiw6,df1))
def f2(w2,aiw6,df1):
    ansdo = ((w2/w2-aiw6)*df1)
    ans4 = int(ansdo)
    answer = QLabel(ans4,w)
    answer.move(75,300)
    answer.show()


def arch():
    l_archimedes = QLabel("Archimedes' Law",w)
    l_archimedes.move(25,80)
    l_archimedes.show()
    l_archimedes2 = QLabel("Density of Object/Density of Fluid = Weight/(Weight - Apparent Immersed Weight)",w)
    l_archimedes2.move(25,110)
    l_archimedes2.show()
    Archimedeslaw = QLabel("What Do You Want to Solve For:",w)
    Archimedeslaw.move(25,145)
    Archimedeslaw.show()
    dop = QPushButton("Density of Object",w)
    dop.move(25,160)
    dop.show()
    dop.clicked.connect(ObjectDensity)


    DF = QPushButton("Density of Fluid",w)
    DF.move(200,160)
    DF.show()
    Weight = QPushButton("Weight",w)
    Weight.move(375,160)
    Weight.show()
    AIW = QPushButton("Apperent Immersed Weight",w)
    AIW.move(500,160)
    AIW.show()

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
w = QWidget()
w.resize(900,600)
w.move(460,0)
w.setWindowTitle("Physics Laws")
L1 = QLabel("Welcome To Physics Laws",w,)
L1.move(25,0)
b1 = QPushButton("Archimedes Law",w)
b1.move(25,45)
b1.clicked.connect(arch)









w. show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PYQT5: After I press button to return value, The app closes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52304519/pyqt5-after-i-press-button-to-return-value-the-app-closes)

Comment: same app really. but now i have no idea why it isnt working, i am a beginner. i would appreciate your help debugging this.

Comment: In SO you should not publish the same question several times, do not you think that it will bore us ?, If you want your question to be attractive and therefore we are interested in helping you, there are many ways to do it, such as showing what you have done, and showing the message of error, etc. Do not post the same question several times. read [ask] and review the [tour]

Comment: I am sorry. I didnt know. thank you anyways in your response. i will keep that in mind next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QWidget, QApplication, QPushButton, QLabel,
                             QToolTip, QCheckBox, QLCDNumber,
                             QLineEdit, QInputDialog)    # ??? just compile the modules like this
from PyQt5.QtGui     import QIcon

def ObjectDensity():
    dflabel = QLabel("Please Enter Density of Fluid: ",w)
    dflabel.move(25,220)
    dflabel.show()
    dfte = QLineEdit(w)
    dfte.move(25,260)
    dfte.show()
    Weight2 = QLabel("Please Enter Weight:",w)
    Weight2.move(25,300)
    Weight2.show()
    Wte = QLineEdit(w)
    Wte.move(25,340)
    Wte.show()
    AIW2 = QLabel("Enter Apperent Immersed Weight: ",w)
    AIW2.move(25,380)
    AIW2.show()
    aiwte = QLineEdit(w)
    aiwte.move(25,420)
    aiwte.show()
    ansbutton = QPushButton("Submit",w)
    ansbutton.move(50,480)
    ansbutton.show()
    ansbutton.clicked.connect(lambda: f1(dfte,Wte,aiwte )) #,ansdo)) # <------------------
    # df1 = dfte.text()
    # w2 = Wte.text()
    # aiw6 = aiwte.text()

def f1(dfte,Wte,aiwte):  #,ansdo):                                   # <------------------
    df1 = int(dfte.text())
    w2 = int(Wte.text())
    aiw6 = int(aiwte.text())
    # ansdo = ((w2/w2-aiw6)*df1)
    # ans4 = int(ansdo)
    ans = QPushButton("press to show answer", w)

    #ans.move(50,250)
    ans.move(50, 520)                                                # <------------------
    ans.show()

    answer.hide()                                                    # <------------------

    ans.clicked.connect(lambda: f2(w2, aiw6, df1))

def f2(w2, aiw6, df1):
    print("def f2(w2=`{}`, \naiw6=`{}`, \ndf1=`{}`):".format(w2, aiw6, df1) )
    ansdo = ((w2/w2-aiw6)*df1)                                       #  w2/w2 = 1  <--- ???
    #ans4 = int(ansdo)
    #answer = QLabel(ans4, w)
    #answer.move(75,300)
    answer.setText(str(ansdo))                                        # <------------------
    answer.show()                                                     # <------------------


def arch():
    l_archimedes = QLabel("Archimedes' Law",w)
    l_archimedes.move(25,80)
    l_archimedes.show()
    l_archimedes2 = QLabel("Density of Object/Density of Fluid = Weight/(Weight - Apparent Immersed Weight)",w)
    l_archimedes2.move(25,110)
    l_archimedes2.show()
    Archimedeslaw = QLabel("What Do You Want to Solve For:",w)
    Archimedeslaw.move(25,145)
    Archimedeslaw.show()
    dop = QPushButton("Density of Object",w)
    dop.move(25,160)
    dop.show()
    dop.clicked.connect(ObjectDensity)


    DF = QPushButton("Density of Fluid",w)
    DF.move(200,160)
    DF.show()
    Weight = QPushButton("Weight",w)
    Weight.move(375,160)
    Weight.show()
    AIW = QPushButton("Apperent Immersed Weight",w)
    AIW.move(500,160)
    AIW.show()

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
w = QWidget()
w.resize(900,600)
w.move(460,0)
w.setWindowTitle("Physics Laws")
L1 = QLabel("Welcome To Physics Laws",w,)
L1.move(25,0)
b1 = QPushButton("Archimedes Law",w)
b1.move(25,45)
b1.clicked.connect(arch)

answer = QLabel(w)                                                  # <------------------
answer.move(50, 550)                                                # <------------------


w. show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Comment: @Hamza Maharmeh The world is not without good people. Good luck to you.